# Change single to cluster hadoop installation keeping persisted data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm going to do a Hadoop POC in a production environment. The POC consists of:
 1. Receive lots of (real life) events
 2. Accumulate them to have a set of events with enough size
 3. Persist the set of events in a single file HDFS

In case the POC is successful, I want to install a cluster environment but I need to keep the data persisted in the single cluster installation (POC).

Then, the question: How difficult is to migrate the data already persisted in HDFS single cluster to a real cluster HDFS environment?

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad english)
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to migrate anything.

If you're running Hadoop in Pseudo distributed mode, all you need to do is add datanodes that are pointing at your existing namenode and that's it!

I would like to point out

> Persist the set of events in a single file HDFS

I'm not sure about making "a single file", but I suggest you do periodic checkpointing. What if the stream fails? How do you catch dropped events? Spark, Flume, Kafka Connect, NiFi, etc can allow you to do this.

And if all you're doing is streaming events, and want to store them for a variable time period, then Kafka is more built for that use case. You don't necessarily need Hadoop. Push events to Kafka, consume them *where it makes sense*, for example, a search engine or a database (Hadoop is not a database)

Comment: First, thanks for your resonse !! ..... Yes, we're using a hand-made event-memory-collector (maybe in a future we integrate flink). The collector summarizes data every 10 minutes and then this data is persisted in hadoop. If the application goes down we lose 10 minutes of data. This point will be addressed in a future with rabbitMQ or Kafka. We're also implementing map reduces, for that reason we choice hadoop.

Comment: In my few years of experience with Hadoop, I find no enterprises actually writing MapReduce code. Nowadays, it's Spark. And if you're in the cloud, then you're writing to S3, for example, not HDFS